# Angular 15: Empty ActivatedRoute params in Functional Route Guards

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router-guards

I use new functional guards like:

```
export function AuthGuard() {
  const route = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  const authService = inject(AuthService);

  return authService.state$.subscribe((user) => {
    return user.uuid === route.snapshot.params.uuid;
  });
}
```

In the moment, current data of `route.snapshot.params` is empty. Subscription on Router events or ParamsMap does not give result.

Otherwise, when i use class-based guards with `CanActivate`, route data from `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` works perfectly, but `authService` get only first emit with `undefined`.

I figured out a workaround with placing `combineLatest([route, authService])` with redirects in the Component, that need's this Guard.

I'm stuck. No way.

**Solution**: the main problem was in using `BehaviorSubject` in my `authService`, replacing to `ReplaySubject` solved first problem. `Resolver` usage solved the second part.

Comment: I don't think you have to subscribe inside the guard, just return the observable itself. Use pipe(tap(...)) instead to get your side effect.

Comment: @Loop - In functional guards it possible to use boolean return - Official Docs https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#canactivate-requiring-authentication -> "src/app/auth/auth.guard.ts (v2)" code example.

Comment: @Loop - Thank you for guiding me. I have read the documentation below more carefully and realized that it is need to use resolve - [link](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) and get user auth state before guard

Comment: Using subscribe you are not returning a boolean, you are returning an instance of subscription. If I had to guess, this would evaluate as truthy because its javascript and non null objects are evaluated as true.

Comment: @Loop - Thanks. You're definitely right. I checked and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to inject `ActivatedRoute`. If you want to read params from snapshot, your guard could look like this:

```js
export function authGuard(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);

  return authService.state$.subscribe((user) => {
    return user.uuid === snapshot.params.uuid;
  });
}
```

Please note here, that I've added `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` as function param, instead of `ActivatedRoute`. 
Now when you assign this function to `canActivate` in route definition just make sure you pass snapshot to this function:

```js
{
  path: ':uuid',
  canActivate: [(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => authGuard(snapshot)],
},
```

Comment: `(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => authGuard(snapshot)` - it is genius! Thanks a lot!